# How to update an input field in angular and make it persistent through the usage of the factory?

Tags: html, angularjs, mean-stack

I managed to create a blog based upon an example on https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/, in which I added more features such as:

- Edit a post
- Delete a post

However, **although changes were successful**, but I am still not able to make the changes **persistent** even when linking the functions  to the factory.

in HTML I have created the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
  <span>{{post.title}}</span>
<br>
<a href = mailto: {{post.email}}>Contact Customer</a>
<span>
   <button ng-click="setEditedPost(post)">Edit Customer Details</button>
   <br>
   <button ng-click ="deletePost(post)">Delete Post</button>
</span>
</div>

<form ng-submit="updatePost(editedPost)">
  <h2>Edit the above Post</h2>
  <input type="text" ng-model="editedPost.title">
  <br>
  <input type="text" ng-model="editedPost.email">
</form>
```

now in the *angularScript.js* file, in controller,  I have written the following:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, posts){
         $scope.posts = posts.posts;

         $scope.setEditedPost = function(post) {
         $scope.editedPost = post;
    }

        $scope.updatePost = function(editedPost) {
        var index = _.findIndex($scope.posts, function(b) {
        return b.id == post.id
    }) 

    posts.update= post

    }

    $scope.deletePost = function(post){
       var index = $scope.posts.indexOf(post)
       alert("are you sure you want delete "+$scope.posts[index].title+"?")
       delete.splice(index, 1)
   }
})
```

In the factory, **I'm aiming at making the data persistent** through the following:

```
    app.factory('posts', ['$http', function($http) {
    var o = {
    posts: []
 };

    o.update = function(post) {
    return $http.post('/posts', post)
        .success(function(data) {
            o.posts[index] = data
        });
   };

   o.delete = function(post) {
      return $http.post('/post', post)
      .success(function(data) {
        o.posts[index] = data
      )}
  }

 }])
```

The **code works fine in the DOM**, but ***it's not persistent*** when refreshing the page

I am assuming that the error is in the factory but I am not sure about that.

Comment: when you refreshing the page all the data in assigned to js variables will clear, if you want persist the data u can use `localStorage` or `sessoinStorage` in browser

Comment: Or, more realistically, use $http to send the updated post to a server-side backend which will save the changes in a database.

Comment: @JBNizet
dear the point is I am using MongoDB and I am not sure on how to update the documents through code

Comment: @K.Toress
Dear, I am interested in that approach.
May you please show me how with a simple example with respect to the above?

Comment: The angular code can't access MongoDB. What you must do is set up a server, which will provide RESTful endpoints to the angular application. This server will receive http requests from the angular application, and will update/read in MongoDB.

Comment: @JBNizet
do you believe this will work:

`router.get('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
    //get the posts, if succeeded then response is
    //posts in JSON format, else provide error
    Post.remove(function(err, posts) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        res.json(posts);
    });
}); `

This what I wrote to delete, as an example but yet no change

Comment: I assume this is Node.js code. I know nothing about node.js. I develop my backend services using Java, not JavaScript.